# Extract substring with set command in CMD script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am not a CMD windows script expert.

I am trying to extract a version number using the set command (*I have to use the set command for internal reasons*).

Here is what I did write in my script:

```
REM Branch is my input    
set Branch=7.8.1
set "MAJOR=%Branch:.=" & set "MINOR=%%Branch:.=" & set "PATCH=%"
echo MAJOR  =  %MAJOR%
echo MINOR  =  %MINOR%
echo PATCH  =  %PATCH%
```

Here is what I get as output:

```
set "MAJOR=7"   & set "MINOR=8"   & set "MINOR=17"   & set "PATCH=8"   & set "PATCH=1"
MAJOR  =  7
MINOR  =  17
PATCH  =  1
```

What I am trying to get is something like:

```
>set "MAJOR=7"   & set "MINOR=8"  & set "PATCH=1"
>MAJOR  =  7
>MINOR  =  8
>PATCH  =  1
```

Comment: You are replacing in the original string `7.8.1` the `.` by `" & set "MINOR=` and also by `" & set "PATCH=`, then putting the two replacement results together, that is why you get the too long result. Does it really have to be a single line? Why is no other command acceptable (like `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%I in ("%Branch%") do set "MAJOR=%%I" & set "MINOR=%%J" & set "PATCH=%%K"`, for instance)?

Comment: At first, write `set "INTER=%Branch:*.=%"`; then use `set "MAJOR=%BRANCH:.=" & rem/"%" & set "MINOR=%INTER:.=" & rem/"%" & set "PATCH=%INTER:*.=%"`…

Comment: Why are you limited to `set`? That makes no sense. You could maybe argue no external .exe files but why can't you use `for`?

Comment: Looks like you were trying to use some dynamic string substitution that we originally created on Dostips.com and has probably been posted on StackOverFlow as well by Antonio.  Please show us what website on the web you got this code from.

Comment: Here is the original post from [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429&start=30#p55768). That is a direct link to Antonio's code but I would advise you to read the entire forum thread. Antonio has a slightly less complicated version of this technique earlier in the [thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429#p41066)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a small adaption of an idea, *(originally created within [this external site thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6429), and already specifcally [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) in the comments)*:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Branch=7.8.1"
Set "Vars=Major Minor Patch" & Set "p=%%"
Set "v=%Vars: =" & Set "s=!Branch:*.=!" & Call Set "!v!=!p!Branch:.!s!=!p!" & Set "Branch=!s!" & Set "v=%" & Set "!v!=!s!"
Echo Major: %Major%, Minor: %Minor%, Patch: %Patch%
Pause
```

Comment: Nor `Set "s="` neither `Set "v="` variables needs to be initialized...

Answer (score 5):

This is another, perhaps simpler, way to do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Branch=7.8.1"
set "MAJOR=%Branch:.=" & (if not defined MINOR (set "v=MINOR") else set "v=PATCH") & set "!v!=%"
echo MAJOR  =  %MAJOR%
echo MINOR  =  %MINOR%
echo PATCH  =  %PATCH%
```

**EDIT 2021/12/20:** *New method added*

I think this is the simplest way to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Branch=7.8.1"
set "MAJOR=%Branch:.=" & set "MINOR=!PATCH!" & set "PATCH=%"

echo MAJOR  =  %MAJOR%
echo MINOR  =  %MINOR%
echo PATCH  =  %PATCH%
```

Answer (score 3):

Why is the following command line using `for /F` not acceptable?

```cmd
set "Branch=7.8.1"
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%I in ("%Branch%") do set "MAJOR=%%I" & set "MINOR=%%J" & set "PATCH=%%K"
set "MAJOR" & set "MINOR" & set "PATCH" & rem // (just to return results)
```

This is most straight forward and quite easy to understand.

---

Anyway, a method using `set` consisting of two lines is this:

```cmd
set "Branch=7.8.1"
set "INTER=%Branch:*.=%" & rem // (this must be on a separate line)
set "MAJOR=%BRANCH:.=" & rem/"%" & set "MINOR=%INTER:.=" & rem/"%" & set "PATCH=%INTER:*.=%"
set "MAJOR" & set "MINOR" & set "PATCH" & rem // (just to return results)
```

---

Here is a method consisting of only a single line, requiring [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```cmd
set "Branch=7.8.1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PATCH=" & rem // (this variable must be initially cleared)
set "MAJOR=%Branch:.=" & (if defined PATCH set "MINOR=!PATCH!") & set "PATCH=%"
set "MAJOR" & set "MINOR" & set "PATCH" & rem // (just to return results)
endlocal
```

The initialisation command `set "PATCH="` may be combined with the subsequent line using `&`.

---

And this is a method with a single line too, not requiring [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), but relying on the fact that the third number (to be stored in variable `PATCH`) does not feature leading zeros:

```cmd
set "Branch=7.8.1"
set "PATCH=" & rem // (this variable must be initially cleared)
set "MAJOR=%Branch:.=" & (if defined PATCH set /A "MINOR=PATCH") & set "PATCH=%"
set "MAJOR" & set "MINOR" & set "PATCH" & rem // (just to return results)
```

Again the line `set "PATCH="` may be combined with the following one by `&`.