# How to get value out of html page with javascript or windows batch

Tags: html, batch-file, jscript

need to extraxt a value(dip) out of a html

`</span><span class="pron dpron">/<span class="ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1">buːm</span>/</span></span></div><div class="pos-body">`

my code leads into:
microsoft jscript runtime error object doesn't support this property or method

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

curl https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/boom >phoneme.html

set "htmlfile=phoneme.html"

rem // invoke JScript hybrid code and capture its output
for /f %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%htmlfile%"') do set "converted=%%I"

echo %converted%

rem // end main runtime
PAUSE
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    DOM = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    htmlfile = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1),
    html = htmlfile.ReadAll();

DOM.write(html);
htmlfile.Close();

var scrape = DOM.getElementsByTagName('pron dpron').getElementsByClassName('ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1')[0].innerText;
WSH.Echo(scrape.match(/^.*=\s+(\S+).*$/)[0]);
```

copy&pasted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893147/need-to-parse-out-string-from-html-document-in-a-batch-file) and slightly edited.

need to get "bu:m" into a value or echoed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Using an HTML-parser, like [tag:xidel], would imo be much simpler: `xidel -s "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/boom" -e "(//span[@class='us dpron-i '])[1]/span/span[@class='ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1']"`.

Comment: @Reino: Thank you! xidel -s "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/boom" -e "(//span[@class='pron dpron']/span[@class='ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1'])[1]" did the trick, now I need to find a way to get the Unicode out of it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the tips.
With @Reino and [Echo-ing unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280703/echo-ing-unicode-character) I was able to get what I need.

```html
@ECHO OFF
chcp 65001

xidel -s "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/boom" -e "(//span[@class='pron dpron']/span[@class='ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1'])[1]"

PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: I indicated to use `chcp 65001` command to generate the Unicode character in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75677045/778560) three days ago...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JScript in order to extract such a value from the .html file; you can do it directly with a Batch file.

If the structure of the desired line is always the same:

```
<span class="pro">/<span class="dip">buːm</span>/</span>
```

... you can do it as simple as this line:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=</>" %%a in ('findstr "\"dip\"" phoneme.html') do set "dip=%%a"
echo %dip%
```

If the line could change, first get the line with `"dip"` value via a `findstr` command, and then extract the `dip` value:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "\"dip\"" phoneme.html') do set "html=%%a"
set "dip=%html:*"dip">=%"
set "dip=%dip:<=" & rem "%"
echo %dip%
```

---

*New code added*

This new method was designed and extracted from OP's *comments*...

**1-** In your question you specified that you are looking for this string: `"dip"`. However, in your comment it seems that the real string you want is this: `"ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1"`. Please, note that the second string is *very different* than the first one because *it contain spaces* and most Batch commands are sensitive to spaces, so the code must be modified accordingly. BTW it is very bad "netiquette" that you provide us a certain data, test the code we wrote with *different data*, and then you say: "Your code not works"! Did you tested our code with the data *you* provided?

**2-** In my answer I specified: *"If the structure of the desired line is always the same:"*

```
<span class="pro">/<span class="dip">buːm</span>/</span>
```

However, it seems that the real line is *very different*:

```
</span><span class="pron dpron">/<span class="ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1">buːm</span>/</span></span> <span class="us dpron-i "><span class="region dreg">us</span><span class="daud"> converted= /span span class="pron dpron" / span class="ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1" buːm /span / /span /span span class="us dpron-i " span class="region dreg" us /span span class="daud"
```

I added: *"If the line could change..."* use the second code.

Why did you tested the first code if the real line is *entirely different* than the line you posted? You should use the second code instead... The aid could over-complicate if simple instructions are not followed...

**3-** In your comment you indicated that the html file is created with this line:

```
curl dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/boom
```

When I tested such a line I got this:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

... but your complaint was: `I just get: 'a href='https:'`

I really don't know what else to say...

---

I prepared a test file with this contents:

```
Any other line...
</span><span class="pron dpron">/<span class="ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1">buːm</span>/</span></span> <span class="us dpron-i "><span class="region dreg">us</span><span class="daud"> converted= /span span class="pron dpron" / span class="ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1" buːm /span / /span /span span class="us dpron-i " span class="region dreg" us /span span class="daud"
Any other line...
```

This is the new code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM  curl dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/boom > phoneme.html

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"\"ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1\"" phoneme.html') do set "html=%%a"
set "dip=%html:*"ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1">=%"
set "dip=%dip:<=" & rem "%"
echo %dip%
```

... and this is the output:

```
bu╦Ém
```

It seems that the output contain an Unicode character that, of course, can *not* be properly managed by a Batch file...  **`:(`**

PS - The Unicode character *could be* properly generated if `chcp 65001` command is used...

Comment: Hmm - `set "firststring=%wholestring:uniquesubstring=" & set stringafter="%"` ... Good voodoo

Comment: I just get: 'a href='https:'

Comment: '@echo off
setlocal

curl https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/boom >factions_phoneme.html

set "htmlfile=factions_phoneme.html"
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

for /F "tokens=3 delims=</>" %%a in ('findstr "\"ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1\"" factions_phoneme.html') do set "dip=%%a"
echo %dip%

Pause
GOTO :EOF'

Comment: @Magoo: Do you like this voodoo? I invite you to review [the whole story](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)... But beware! It could be dangerous... Really! **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini : Evidently an old trick, but I'd not seen it before. Any clue why it's not used on SO more often?

Comment: @Aacini: first, I'm sorry. It was not my intention to break the netiquette. second: I wasn't aware that spaces have such an impact. In my commented code, the https is gone in StackOverflow. so my link is still working. with your new code I get back: '/╦êm╩îs.t├ª╩â/' - but you already said that it is not possible to handle Unicode. so I still ned a JScript code? Many thanks. Edit: edited the original code in my post to the used link.

Comment: @Magoo: Mmmm... If you open my page and search for "split", you'll get _a lot_ of answers based on this method. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600775/split-string-with-string-as-delimiter/33131797#33131797), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808255/split-by-three-spaces-batchscript/48811742#48811742), etc... [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696809/778560) is an answer from another author, and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70436066/extract-substring-with-set-command-in-cmd-script) there are 3 similar answers from different people.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "converted=<span class="pro">/<span class="dip">bu:m</span>/</span>"
SET converted
SET "converted=%converted:<= %"
SET "converted=%converted:>= %"
SET "grab="
FOR %%e IN (%converted%) DO IF DEFINED grab (
 SET "converted=%%e"
 GOTO done
 ) ELSE IF %%e=="dip" SET "grab=y"
:done
SET converted
GOTO :EOF
```

Replace the redirectors with spaces, then process the value as a series of space-separated tokens. When the token `"dip"` appears, set `grab` to obtain the next token, grab it and exit the `for`.

Note : `converted` will be mangled if `"dip"` does not appear.
And  : What appears to be a colon between `bu` and `m` is some unicode character. I replaced it with a colon for testing.

Comment: Hi, 
the output is following:
'converted=</span><span class="pron dpron">/<span class="ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1">bu╦Ém</span>/</span></span> <span class="us dpron-i "><span class="region dreg">us</span><span class="daud">
converted= /span  span class="pron dpron" / span class="ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1" bu╦Ém /span / /span  /span   span class="us dpron-i "  span class="region dreg" us /span  span class="daud"'

Comment: Since your new string does not contain `"dip"`, you need to change `"dip"` to `"ipa dipa lpr-2 lpl-1"` to match the appropriate substring.

Comment: changed it and it seems to work, but as Aacini said there is still a issue with the Unicode. :( Do you have an idea how to get this run/fixed?